# Finding the surface of intersection of 2 cylinders

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $R=\{(x,y,z): x^2+z^2\leq 1, y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$. Compute the area of its boundary $\partial R$.

The formula is $\int_D\sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2}dxdy$ and $z=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, (I think). But what should the bound be. Any hints? Thanks

Comment: Like in picture  here?                                                               http://paulbourke.net/geometry/cylinders/

Comment: I would say, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html